# e.target.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to pass the target value on click and then change the state of the prop. I am getting an error that e.target.value is undefined. Not really sure if im not passing the prop and the value properly.

Ive tried different things. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
btnActiveInactive = (e, isactive) => {
  var clickedButton = e.target.value;
  console.log(isactive);
  if (clickedButton === "true") {
    this.setState({
      isactive: true,
    });
  }
  if (clickedButton === "false") {
    this.setState({
      isactive: false,
    });
  }
};


<ButtonGroup
  className="text-center"
  style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
  aria-label="Basic example"
  value={this.props.isActive}
>
  <Button
    onClick={(e) =>
      this.btnActiveInactive(this.state.isactive)
    }
    id="inactive"
    variant="outline-danger" //{this.state.inactiveVariant}
    name="inactive"
    value="false"
  >
    Inactive
  </Button>
  <Button
    onClick={(e) =>
      this.btnActiveInactive(this.state.isactive)
    }
    id="active"
    variant="success" //{this.state.activeVariant}
    name="active"
    value="true"
  >
    Active
  </Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `btnActiveInactive` takes in two parameters:

```
btnActiveInactive = (e, isactive) => {
...
```

so in your button, you need to pass in the parameters correctly:

```
 onClick={(e) => this.btnActiveInactive(e, this.state.isactive)
```